# ordering a list in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of Employee objects .Employee Class can be as below:

```
Class Emplyoyee
{
    public string name;
    public string DateOFJoining; //Please note here date is in string format
}
```

Now i want to display the list of employee with latest employee on top so am using below code for it :

```
List<Employee> lst = GetEmployes();          
lst = lst.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateOFJoining).ToList();

//Here binding to the repeater
rptEmp.DataSource = lst.Take(2);
rptEmp.DataBind();
```

Problem: Here its ordering treating date as string .But i want to order by date.Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not part of any answer, but you should `Take(2)` before you `ToList()` to avoid creating a large list that you then throw away; Code would be `lst = lst.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateOFJoining).Take(2).ToList()`.

Comment: thank you chris,that was a very useful tip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to convert `x.DateOfJoining` into a `DateTime` in the `OrderByDescending` expression. If you're confident in the quality of your dates, you could try:

```
lst = lst.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.DateOfJoining)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have `Employee` implement the `System.IComparable` interface. and then just use the `List.Sort()` method to order the employees.

for example:

```
Class Employee : IComparable
{
    public string name;
    public string DateOFJoining; //Please note here date is in string format

    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        if(obj is Employee) {
            Employee= (Employee) obj;

            return Convert.ToDateTime(DateOfJoining).CompareTo(Convert.ToDateTime(e.DateOfJoining));
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("object is not an Employee");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course you need to make sure that DateOFJoining contains a correctly formatted date. (otherwise Convert will throw an exception)